# Fill fields from Google sheet into a Google form based on answer

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, google-forms

I help run golf games/tournaments for my local golf club (pro bono ofcourse!). We have moved all scoring and leaderboards online thru Google sheets and Google forms. I have decent knowledge of Excel macros and visual basic, but not much of JavaScript.

I have a Google sheet with all details of golfers in a flight/4-ball group. I want to populate the names of golfers in the hole-wise scoring form whenever one selects their flight/4-ball group. Let's say, of 1st question is a drop down with all 4-ball details, and if I select 2nd 4-ball group, the fields of golfer names of that 4-ball should get populated into the same form from the Google sheet.

Is it possible? Been struggling for a while now. Any help will be most welcome.

Comment: Look how condensed your question is. Please format your question so it is easy to read

Comment: I've improved your formatting a little bit.

Comment: Thank you so much Mehdi & Thomas. Noted your directions.

Comment: You can't programmatically update an "In Progress" form, e.g. a Google Form is a static object to a respondent. You can use "go to page" answer-based branching with a predefined form. Alternately, you can programmatically construct a new form based on a submitted form. Otherwise, you'll need to use traditional html web forms, and the `google.script.____` pattern for data exchange